# How to use specific print settings for print job in c# application?

Tags: c#, printing

I need to print a pdf with specific printer settings from my c# application. Its required that the printer uses best quality in image compression, fine setting for the pattern option and 600 dpi as resolution.

[image: Printer Settings]

Currently I try to set these values with the PrintParams, but the result is not the same as when I set the values manually with the printer settings GUI.

Any idea how to set these values?

```
using (Document doc = new Document(fi.FullName))
                {
                    if (doc != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("created print document object with given pdf");
                    }

                    using (PrintUserParams userParams = new PrintUserParams())
                    {
                        if (userParams != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("created user parameters for printing");
                        }


                        userParams.PrintParams.BinaryOK = false;
                        userParams.StartPage = 0;
                        userParams.EndPage = doc.NumPages;
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("document contains {0} pages", doc.NumPages));

                        userParams.NCopies = 1;
                        userParams.ShrinkToFit = false;
                        userParams.PrintParams.ShrinkToFit = false;
                        userParams.PrintParams.ExpandToFit = false;                           
                        userParams.DeviceName = printerName;
                        userParams.PrintParams.BitmapResolution = 600;
                        userParams.PrintParams.OptimizeForSpeed = false;
                        userParams.PrintParams.FlattenInfoExternalDPI = 600;
                        userParams.PrintParams.GradientResolution = 600;
                        userParams.PrintParams.UseFullResolutionJP2KData = false;


                        doc.Print(userParams, null);

                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("document {0} has been sent to printer {1}", fi.FullName, printerName));
                    }                           
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using DEVMODE instead PrintUserParams.You can open printer properties from c# using windows api and modify/save DEVMODE.